Can Siesta be used to compute XPS spectrum in periodic system?
I am still familiarizing myself with DFT calculations in periodic systems using pseudo potentials. I want to compute the XPS spectrum for our iron oxide surface using SIESTA. I generated my pseudo potentials for both neutral and core ionized species using APE.
SIESTA fails with a weird error message, which makes me think that it might somehow fail to properly read/understand the core ionized pseudo potential.
My question is: has anyone ever used SIESTA for this, and if the code is able to do calculations with core ionized pseudos at all?
Thanks in advance for any hint and insight!

+1. Welcome to our community.
